# Identity Column Auto Increment with current year

Tags: sql, auto-increment

I have Student table having RegNo. as Identity column among others.Now I want that this RegNo. should auto increment with current year.I mean I only want this "2014-001"..."2014-002'....so on.I mean taking current year and incremented integers only.In the next year again starting form 1 with new year.Please tell me the complete procedure I mean where the required function should be written.Where should the function be called?In stored procedure 'Insert_Student_Info' or separate somewhere?Please do not say it's dublicate...I 'm in need of it's solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So there you go.

Make a function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [ufn_GetNextID]() 
    returns varchar(10) 
as 
begin 
    declare @lastval char(10) 
    set @lastval = (select max(ID) from tbl_Student) 
    if @lastval is null set @lastval = '001' 
    else
     set @lastval = right(@lastval,3) + 1 
    return CAST(DATEPART(year,GETDATE()) as varchar) +'-'+ @lastval
end
GO
```

Comment: @Ashsih Charan...this function is good but doesnot increment value.It shows 2014-1,2014-1,2014-1...in all rows

Comment: I've tested. it works. What is the max value in your table currently?